# Hide Tax in subtotal to guests in magento

Tags: magento

I have seen a couple variations of this question but I don't think they hit what I am trying to do spot on.

My problem is, if a guest puts something into their cart and they view their cart they see the tax for it.  It is unnecessary to show the tax to a customer before we know what state they live in.

Now, if they log in and are not in our state the tax does not show.  Is it possible to hide tax from guests (Who have not logged in).

Using magento 1.5.1

Comment: What are your tax calculations based on set to in the admin?

Comment: Hah... I had to set the default tax destination calculation to none... silly me.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can associate different layout updates to customer_logged_in and customer_logged_out handles in order to differentiate layout behaviour but I don't think that this is the point.

Even if you know whether a customer is logged in or not, you won't know which is the tax destination until the checkout phase, so you probably have to show tax information only on the order review step of the checkout process.

Does it sounds right?
Regards, Alessandro

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The tax display is the same block for both the subtotal (Right side of the cart) and the check out pages.  I would love to see it not display at all on the cart.